# How do I keep a floating div in place when switching a smaller screen?

Tags: html, html-email, signature

I created an html email signature that looks fine on a sent email on the computer, but when looking at the signature on an iphone the imageholder div shifts above the textholder. How do I make them stay in the same line even on smaller screens?

```html
    <div id="textcontainer"  style="font-family:helvetica; font- 
    size:12px;">
    <br><br><br>
    
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="width:360px; height:195px; font-family: 
    futura;">
    
    <div id="imageholder" style="width:150px; height:149px; float:left; 
    padding:10px;">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x8x5Gbx/image.png">
    </div>
    <div id="textholder" style="width:175px; height:150px; float:left; 
    padding-top:25px; padding-left:0px; padding-bottom:10px; padding- 
    right:10px;">
    <font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;"> 
    Name</font><br>
    <font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;"> . 
    Title</font><br>
    <font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;"> O 
    </font><font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px;"> (888) 888- 
    8888</font><br>
    <font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:14px; padding-left:8px;"> F 
    </font><font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px;"> &nbsp;(888) 
    888-8888</font><br>
    <font style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;"> 
    Company name</font>



    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div><font style="color:#000000; font-size:12px;">disclaimer</font>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need the signature to be in columns. First column for image and second for the other details (name, title etc).

Comment: if you're doing html email then u should use table, it is the best way to do

Answer (score 0):

Dont use div's in html mails, thats not gonna work. Use tables, something like this:

```
<table colspan="0" rowspan="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="150" style="width:150px">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x8x5Gbx/image.png" style="width:150px; height:149px;">
        </td>
        <td width="175">
        <table colspan="0" rowspan="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" style="color:#0F2E51; font-size:16px; line-height: 20px; padding-left:8px; font-family:helvetica;">
                            Name<br>
                            . Title<br>
                            O (888) 888- 8888<br>
                            F  (888) 888-8888<br>
                            Company name<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>                     
        </table>            
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:#000000; font-size:12px;">
            disclaimer
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```